# How should i make Assignment Files safe in Uniface 9.7

Tags: security, uniface

How should i make Assignment Files safe?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put passwords in assignment files.
And if you can't avoid that, then use the path scrambler.

Comment: What is the path scrambler? I don't know it. Is it from rocket software? Okay, i find it on the documentation of uniface. See here: https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/Uniface/10/uniface/_reference/executables/pathscrambler_exe.htm